# What is causing background: none to be overriden on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this page [removed link] what is causing `background: none!important;` to apply on body? I can't find it... it isn't CSS right?

DevTools in Chrome doesn't show anything, Firefox Developer shows a little more, it says inline but if I click the link it goes to first css file it found on a page (Bootstrap, which doesn't have that style). There is `ev` tag (event listener) just after opening `<body>`, but I am not sure if that applies background

[image]

Comment: Line 875 of your code has <style>body{background:none!important}</style>. Without any further information on how this is added to the page, I'm not sure how we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an element here:

```
<div class="off">
    <style>body{background:none!important}</style>
</div>
```

If you delete this it fixes it.

It's peculiar because the class of 'off' hides this element and yet the style is still applied.